# Filling dataGrid with LINQ returned IEnumerable?

Tags: sql, silverlight, linq, datagrid, return

I am trying to fill a datagrid (called dgDeelnemers) with the data from my databank, which I get using the following LINQ method.

```
[OperationContract]
public IEnumerable<Inschrijvingen> getInschrijvingen()
{
    var query = (from p in dc.Inschrijvingens select p);

    IEnumerable<Inschrijvingen> i = query;

    return i;
}
```

And then I assign the data to my datagrid in the view using the following code.

```
  public partial class Deelnemers : UserControl
    {
        public Deelnemers()
        {
            InschrijvingenServiceClient client = new InschrijvingenServiceClient();

            client.getInschrijvingenCompleted += new EventHandler<getInschrijvingenCompletedEventArgs>(client_getInschrijvingenCompleted);
            client.getInschrijvingenAsync();
        }

        void client_getInschrijvingenCompleted(object sender, getInschrijvingenCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Error != null)
                lblDeelnemers.Content = e.Error.ToString();
            else
                dgDeelnemers.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }
    }
```

But when I navigate to the page I get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at
>   OndernemersAward.Views.Deelnemers.client_getInschrijvingenCompleted(Object
>   sender, getInschrijvingenCompletedEventArgs e)    at
>   OndernemersAward.InschrijvingenServiceReference.InschrijvingenServiceClient.OngetInschrijvingenCompleted(Object
>   state)

I'm not sure what's causing this, but the return value of 'i' I think is correct.

[image]

Thank you for taking your time to read this and help me, I greatly appreciate it!
Thomas

Comment: Is the code above a usercontrol you're trying to put into another usercontrol (i.e. SL page) or is it the page itself?

Comment: Yes, it's a usercontrol I'm trying to put into my main silverlight page. (I navigate to it using a urimapper)

Comment: I'm not seeing InitializeComponent()

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed missing my InitializeComponent().
I keep falling over these really stupid mistakes, people must think I'm really stupid!
Thank you, again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have InitializeComponent()

(taken from my comment) :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your control has rendered by the time the event comes in? Looks like `lblDeelnemers` or `dgDeelnemers` is null. Perhaps don't call `client.getInschrijvingenAsync();` until the control has finished loading.